# What is the difference between ^parentComponent or ^^parentComponent for require in AngularJS 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There are references of using

```
require: {
parent: '^^parent'
}
```

as well as

```
require: {
parent: '^parent'
}
```

at different places. Haven't figured out the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

and

https://toddmotto.com/directive-to-directive-communication-with-require/

> - The ^^ prefix means that this directive searches for the *controller*
>     on ***its parents***.
> - A ^ prefix would make the directive look for the *controller* ***on its
>     own element or its parents***;
> - without any prefix, the directive
>     would look on its ***own element only***.)